# INSERT в цикле через равные интервалы

Tags: postgresql, golang

Пробую сделать вставку записи в цикле в базу postgresql через равные интервалы.

```
package main
import (
     "time"
     "fmt"
     "database/sql"
     _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)
func main() {
     // Connect to db:
     var err error
     db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "host=localhost port=5433 user=postgres 
password=*** dbname=postgres sslmode=disable")
     if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(`1.Error_connect`)
        panic(err)
     }
// INSERT in cycle :
// A = 4_(каждые 4мс)   B = 1000_(одна секунда) //      249_(итераций) = (B/A -1).
ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Millisecond * 4)  // A
go func() {
    for t := range ticker.C {

        rows, err := db.Query("INSERT INTO public.tbl_sss (p8) VALUES ('ins_01')")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(`1.Error_cycle`)
            panic(err)
        }
        defer rows.Close()
    }
}()
time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 1000)             // B
ticker.Stop()
//
defer db.Close()
}
```

---

```
пишет : t declared and not used
```

Коннект и вставка (без блока интервала) - работает.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно делать.

---

upd_1

---

```
package main
import (
        "time"
        "fmt"
        "database/sql"
        _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)
func main() {
    // Connect to db:
    var err error
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "host=localhost port=5433 user=postgres 
                         password=*** dbname=postgres sslmode=disable")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(`1.Error_connect`)
    panic(err)
}
// INSERT in cycle :
// A = 4_(каждые 4мс)   B = 1000_(одна секунда) //      249_(итераций) = (B/A -1).
ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Millisecond * 4)  // A
go func() {
    i := 0
    //for t := range ticker.C {
    for range ticker.C {
        i = i+1
        _, err = db.Exec(`INSERT INTO public.tbl_sss (p8, p11) VALUES ($1, $2)`,"ins_63_A4", i)
        if err != nil {                   // Вставил 232 вместо 249 при А=4.
            fmt.Println(`1.Error_cycle`)  // Вставил 365 вместо 499 при А=2.
            panic(err)                    // Вставил 768 вместо 999 при А=1.
        }
    }
}()
time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 1000)             // B
ticker.Stop()
//
defer db.Close()
}
```

---

Так, при заданном интервале в 4мс (между insert) делал пять замеров, соответственно, получал 234, 227, 240, 132, 229 insert_ов из 249 теоретически возможных (без накладных временных издержек за период = 1000мс). Не пойму *просадку* до 132 (почти в два
раза) и главное, - что её даёт. Кривой код, конфиг постгреса, ..? Было бы в диапазоне, например, 210-240 insert_ов, - посчитал бы за ok. Как правильно сделать тестовый код, чтобы видеть/понять что даёт *просадку* ? Спасибо.

Comment: Ругается на то, что вы объявили t, но так и не использовали, почему? Не знаю, не разбираюсь в Go. Вы, вроде в цикле присваивает переменной t значение, и не вызываете её дальше.

Comment: Да, Вы верно подметили, спасибо, по ошибке - я это понял. Была вставка INSERT двух значений : "INSERT INTO public.tbl_sss (p8, p2) VALUES ('ins_01', t)" с такой ошибкой. Вот VALUES ('ins_01', t) здесь t, который вставлял в поле text в postgresql ...  Думал косяк с типом данных, - потом решил убрать t .. в общем - накосячил.

Comment: Убрал t. Сделал так : for range ticker.C { ... Получил вставку в таблицу 30 записей. Рассчитывал на 249. Между соседними записями интервалы времени ~ одинаковое, например : '2018-04-07 18:12:01.966703+00' и '2018-04-07 18:12:01.994705+00' Почему только 30 записей - не пойму. Подскажите, плиз.

Comment: Это уже логическая ошибка, я не знаю в чем дело, попробуйте написать юнит тесты, проверьте таймер,  цикл, в общем, все, в чем может быть ошибка.

Comment: вместо ` defer rows.Close()` попробуйте закрывать сразу `rows.Close()`

Comment: @biosckon , спасибо, Ваша коррекция дала хороший результат : при  заданном интервале в 4мс получил от 153 до 240 инсертов (делал пять замеров, соответственно, получал 153, 213, 240, 169, 231 вставок из 249 максимально возможных). Я правильно понимаю, что есть временные накладные расходы на insert, которые и дают уменьшение их числа от максимально возможных (249 инсертов за 1000мс при интервале 4мс), причём эти издержки всегда сильно разные .. Думаю, мой код сильно кривой, - как правильно делать, чтобы стабилизировать эти временные расходы?

Comment: @Alex стабилизировать временные параметры будет сложно для любой SQL базы. Думаю нужно будет уменьшить общее количество вызовов к базе `db.Query(...`. Т.е. аккумулируйте данные и делаете `db.Query("INSERT...` несколькими значениями в 3-4 раза большим временным интервалом. И еще лучше подизайнить так что-бы не накладывать строгие временные рамки на базу. Для таких вешей лучше будет что ниить вроде redis или trantool.

Comment: @biosckon , добавил в теле вопроса, там видно, что делал интервал между вставками 4мс , 2мс и 1мс всё за одинаковый период, равный одной секунде. Думаю, вставка двух сотен (точнее 249) записей за одну секунду - не должно быть в тягость ... Вопрос в том, почему проседает почти в два раза на одном и том же примере с постоянным параметром в 4мс.

Comment: ну если мы тут экперементируем то попробуте ваш `db.Exec(` вызвать в го-рутине `go func(i int){ db.Exec(... ) }(i)`

Comment: возможно под вашу задачу подойдёт https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#hdr-Bulk_imports

Answer (score 0):

Если не обязательно, чтобы INSERT'ы выполнялись строго последовательно, то с такой частотой INSERT'ов, я думаю, надо будет реализовать пул коннектов к базе, пул worker'ов, канал для заданий. Логика воркера - взять задачу из канала (в этом случае - i), взять свободный коннект из пула, сделать дело, отпустить. Воркеры запустить параллельно. Тогда они будут расхватывать задачи в несколько ниток.

Comment: спасибо за помощь. Я так глубоко не владею темой, делаю первые шаги и задача академическая .. Хотел понять вот это :  при установленном интервале между инсертами в 2мс - вставляет 365 записей в секунду (1мс - 768 записей/сек.) , т.е. железо так справляется. Почему при более легком варианте в 4мс между инсертами не получается выйти на стабильные 249 инсертов. Откуда этот оверхед и такая нестабильность (130-240 инсертов в секунду). И таки да, хочу пока инсерты последовательно, поэтому и смотрю/прикрутил счетчик.